# Looking for the right design (pattern?) for my webapp and external APIs intgerations

Tags: python, database-design, interfaces, integration

I'm working on a simple CRM (Customer Relationship Management) webapp ([Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) and [Peewee ORM](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)) and I found myself in a situation where I believe that I should have used a design pattern that I may not know yet.

The CRM holds data about customers. I want to offer the ability to interact with the customers, e.g. sending them emails or SMS messages as a part of a campaign.

I want my CRM to support arbitrary number of Email Service Providers and SMS Service Providers. Each provider has its' own specific requirements, for example, some expose an API that expects `GET` requests while others expects `POST`; Authentication methods and schemes vary. Structure of the request vary.

In the beginning I stored for each provider,

1. The type of request it expects to receive (`GET`/`POST`)
2. The API endpoint URL
3. An `f-string` with the template of the request

This way I was able to define a single `Provider` peewee model (database table) and easily interact with the providers using the same functionality.

While adding more providers things got more complex and the previously described solution isn't good enough now. Some providers are expecting to be interacted in a less-trivial manner which does not fit the `request-url-f-string` model that I hoped would be sufficient.

I am able to define each `Provider` as a unique peewee model, but it makes no sense as it will create a database table that will hold exactly one row. Therefore, I now think I should implement a `Provider` interface (using Python Protocols or ABC) that would expose `send` and maybe `check_status` and `postback_handler` methods.

What I'm not sure about is how should the relationship between the interface, the implementing classes (for each provider) and the database should look like. I think that Factory Pattern could be a nice choice here, where I could initialize a provider by doing something like `provider = ProviderFactory(**provider_data)`, where `ProviderData` table should define the type of data that the provider that the row describes is using, so that the Python code would know which other columns are relevant and which should be ignored. So for each provider there should be a row that first describes how its' class is initialized and second populate the columns that are relevant for the class initialization.

I don't like this idea since it would mean that the table would be mostly empty (most columns would be empty) and that every time a new way of initializing a new `Provider` class will arise, the database layout should be updated with additional columns.

Is there a design pattern I am missing here? A best practice? Or maybe my latest idea isn't that bad after all?